# How to prevent overwriting existing data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to make an app for food ordering, I am using an Android Studio and Firebase for data, and I'm new at Firebase Realtime Database, and I have a little problem when I want to add an item to the cart there should have tableNumber, menuName, menudType (i means i's food or drink), quantity, and it should reduce an inventory (I make it simple for inventory naming by menuName). So my problem is

1. Every time I save my cart to Firebase, tableNmber data never save
2. I can't add a new item on the same cart, every time I add a new item, the cart was refreshing and my previous item was updated by the new one
3. Every time I add new item to the cart my inventory not reducing and still in the same quantity

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Here I attach my Firebase Data screenshot. The red circle is my problem at number 1, the Blue circle is number 3.

[image]

And this is my code for adding a new cart and reducing inventory

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    boolean invalid=false;
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Stock st = ds.child(menuName).getValue(Stock.class);
                            for(final Stock s : stock) {
                                if(s.getStockName().equals(menuName)) {
                                    int require = quantity;
                                    if(require >= Integer.parseInt(st.getStockQuantity())){
                                        invalid=true;
                                    } else {
                                        int sisa = Integer.parseInt(st.getStockQuantity()) - require;
                                        String sisa1 = String.valueOf(sisa);
                                        Log.e("stock", sisa1);
                                        Stock stock1 = new Stock(st.getStockName(), String.valueOf(sisa));
                                        db.child(st.getStockName()).setValue(stock1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(invalid==false){
                            writeNewEntry(tables, menuName, date, quantity);
                            startActivity(new Intent(ProductDetails.this, DineIn.class));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void increaseQuantity(){
        quantity = quantity + 1;
        txtQuantity.setText("" + quantity);

    }

    public void decreaseQuantity(){
        if(quantity < 1){
            quantity = quantity - 1;
            txtQuantity.setText("" + quantity);
        }
    }

    private void writeNewEntry(String table, String name, String dates, int q){
        Cart entry = new Cart(table, name, dates, q);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(table).setValue(entry);
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to write it, mg question is why every time i want to add a new item at a cart, it replace the older one? And how if i want to add a new item at cart? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question:

> My question is, why every time I want to add a new item to a cart, it replaces the older one?

This is happening because of the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(table).setValue(entry);
```

You are writing the "entry" object, always to the exact same "table" location. Since every node in Firebase Realtime Database is a Map, then at every new addition it overwrites the old value. To solve this, you might consider using DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart")
        .child(table)
        .push()
        .setValue(entry);
```

Meaning that you'll always generate a new key for each node.

Comment: So when i want to get all item at my cart i just to get the child and the apps will showing all my items at cart?

Comment: Something like that, but you should loop through the results, using "getChildren()" method. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry my late respons, ok i will try, i will inform you if its work as soon as possible. Thank you very much for your response 

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: Sorry for late respons, i was at my ofiice before. So i have been try your suggestion of my problem and it solved, but there have another bug, as you see, a child of my node is table and the values get from tables variable, but when i save a data, no data for table number

Comment: Good to hear that is solved. The fact that you are getting another issue, means that the initial error disappeared and this is good news :) so that basically should be considered another question, because it has another scope and also cannot be answered in a comment. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Oh, okay, well thank you very much , i will post very soon for the question